# how to save image to gallery in kotlin

Tags: android, image, android-studio, kotlin, save

I'm working on a project that add image from user gallery then save it again , I used this code below to make user pick the image and add it to the app and it's worked but I don't know how to save the image (later I will add buttons that will edit image so i want to know how to save it after the edit)

```
lateinit var photo: ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    photo = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.photo);
    val upload = findViewById<Button>(R.id.upload)


    val getaction = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        ActivityResultCallback { uri ->
            photo.setImageURI(uri)
        }
    )

    upload.setOnClickListener {
        getaction.launch("image/*")


    }
```

Comment: `I used this code below to add the image and it's worked but I don't know how to save the image` Add to what? And why would you wanna make a copy to begin with? It is already on your device and 'in gallery'  if it can be picked by user.

Comment: you need not to save it again after setting it to Imageview

Comment: @blackapps i will add some buttons later that will edit the image and then i will save it so i want to know how to save the image , I hope you understand what I am trying to do

Comment: I have no idea what you have if you edited an 'image' hence i have no idea what you wanna save.

Answer (score 1):

//Use below code to save uri to bitmap :

```
        //Create a bitmap using the uri from your code
     Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(c.getContentResolver() , Uri.parse(paths));
```

// And after you have the bitmap you can save it to the storage, do remember you might need permissions depending on where you want to save the image.

```
//Code to save bitmap to image on storage, filePath will be the path you wish to save it to.

    try {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    LOG.i(null, "Save file error!");
    return false;
}
```